Overlay a circle in QGIS
I want to draw a circle over my map (centred on a point) in QGIS 3.28. I am stuck because the Shape Digitizing Toolbar is disabled even though I have created a new Polygon layer and entered Edit mode:

What am I missing?
If there is some other way to achieve this, let me know. I am not wedded to the Shape Digitizing Toolbar but it seems like an obvious choice and it's not working.

Why would you draw a circle when you can create a buffer of a point that will be a circle of fixed radius centred on that point?

Note that not all circles are created equal. If it's created in a projection where Cartesian lengths are meaningless (4326, 3857,...) then you'll either have a circle which isn't, or a circle which looks like it isn't (or both).
